# textillate.js - pause between slides

Tags: slide, pause

i have a simple textillate box with 5 slides.
How can i set a pause between the slides ?

My code:

```
$('.textslide').textillate({
    loop: true,
    minDisplayTime: 4000,
    initialDelay: 1500,
    inEffects: ['fadeInLeft'],
    outEffects: ['fadeOut'],
    in: {
        effect: 'fadeInLeft',
        sync: true,
        delay: 500
    },
    out: {
        effect: 'fadeOutRight',
        sync: true,
        delay: 500
    },
    type: 'char',
    autoStart: true         
})
```